# Expand the env value defined in kubernetes definition to container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, environment-variables, containers, newrelic

I am trying to set some environment variables in docker container, Below is the env definition part from the kubernetes pod definition.

```
              env:
                - name: NRIA_LICENSE_KEY
                  value: NRIA_LICENSE_KEY
                -name:  NRIA_DISPLAY_NAME
                  value: abc-$HOSTNAME
```

When I echo the value of NRIA_DISPLAY_NAME variable in the container, however, I am getting below output, which is not expected.

```
echo $NRIA_DISPLAY_NAME
NRIA_DISPLAY_NAME=abc-\$HOSTNAME
```

**expected output:**

```
    echo $NRIA_DISPLAY_NAME
    NRIA_DISPLAY_NAME=abc-myhostname ($HOSTNAME should be replaced with the actual hostname value)
```

I tried setting it in command tag as well, that didn't work.

```
 command: [ "bash", "-c", "export NRIA_DISPLAY_NAME=abc-$HOSTNAME" ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- name:  NRIA_DISPLAY_NAME
  value: abc-$HOSTNAME
```

should have two changes made to it:

1. Ensure the thing you wish to have substituted is *also* present in the `env:` block -- I know you might think `$HOSTNAME` is universally populated, but that's not always true, and it is for sure not true in the kubernetes mental model
2. Use the syntax `$(INTERPOLATION_HERE)` rather than the bash-centric `$VAR` or `${VAR}`. That syntax is documented in the `PodSpec` reference

Thus:

```
env:
- name: HOSTNAME
  valueFrom:
    fieldRef:
      fieldPath: metadata.name
      # or "status.hostIP" or "spec.nodeName" etc
- name: NRIA_DISPLAY_NAME
  value: abc-$(HOSTNAME)
```